# At what point does Chrome disable autocomplete on form elements? (Research for Chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, autocomplete

I'm writing a Chrome extension that may collect information from form elements (text boxes) on a page. Having said that I want to prevent my extension from collecting user sensitive information.

My first guess is to avoid password fields, which is easy.

The next thing is to avoid text boxes with `autocomplete` disabled. To the best of my knowledge, there're two ways to disable autocomplete:

1> On the input itself.

```
<input type="text" name="n1" id="idInput" autocomplete="Off" />
```

2> On the form element.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" autocomplete="off" action="someurl.com">
```

So I'm currently using the following method to find out if an element has autocomplete off:

```
//Called from within extension's content script
function isAutocompleteOff(elmt)
{
    var ac = elmt.autocomplete;
    if(ac)
    {
        if(ac.toLowerCase() == 'off')
            return true;
    }

    //Try form element itself
    ac = elmt.form.autocomplete;
    if(ac)
    {
        if(ac.toLowerCase() == 'off')
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

var elmt = document.getElementById("idInput");
if(!isAutocompleteOff(elmt))
{
    //Use this control
}
```

The method above seems to work, except on this particular page that I tested it on, when the form comes up to fill out the credit card information the input field does not have the `autocomplete="off"` on it. Here it is from the Chrome debugger:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Card Number" maxlength="16" 
 name="cc_number" id="cc_number" class="cc_number cc_number_required">
```

neither does the form element:

```
<form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="https://pageurl.com"
 id="aspnetForm" _lpchecked="1">
```

and my method above doesn't work on it, but Chrome still doesn't show its auto-fill option for that text box (although it does so on other text boxes on that same page.)

So thus my question. **How else can webpages disable autocomplete in Chrome?**